# How to properly add form in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp

I have a function in jQuery which adds to my `jsp` view a form in this way:

```
$("#mydiv").append("<form class=\"sendMessage\" id=\"" + item.message_id + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" />" +
                "</form><br />");
});
```

I would like to maintain submitting this form action. So I have written this function:

```
$(".sendMessage").submit(function(event) {
    alert("sendMessage");
});
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. However when I have added simply my form directly to my `jsp` view, my submit function has worked.

```
<form class="sendMessage">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to add the form ? Is form looking good and issue is with submit code ?

Comment: This question has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("submit","form.sendmessage",function(){alert("sendMessage");
});
```

Comment: This will be invoked for all forms in my view?

Comment: The 2nd param is a selector so you can do $(document).on("submit","form.sendMessage",function() ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any of this code on DOM ready i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

// Handler for .ready() called.
});

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

??

and are you applying the submit binding on callback of the form being added to the markup via Jquery? because otherwise it might not exist yet.